# Trying to access array element in loop causes segmentation fault, why?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a two dimensional array, which has either 1 or 0 randomly assigned to each coordinate. It works just fine until it gets to the coordinates [20][3]. After that it just throws out "segmentation fault 11".

I am absolutely clueless how or why. Especially since I can create a matrix with 200 * 200 for instance but it still gets the same Problem only at the coordinates [200][3]. So it is somehow always the third y coordinate in the last x coordinate where the error occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  int x, y, i, j ;
  x = 20;
  y = 20;

  int grid [x][y];

  for ( i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    for ( j = 0; j <= y; j++) {

      grid[i][j] = rand() % 2 ;

      printf("grid [%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, grid[i][j]);

    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is an error. Your index can only reach 19, you have to change the loops: for ( i = 0; i < x; i++) { // Note the "<" instead "<="
    for ( j = 0; j < y; j++) {

Comment: @Alexi what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C uses 0-based indexing for arrays. So, for an array defined as

```
int grid [x][y]
```

looping for

```
 for ( i = 0; i <= x; i++) 
   for ( j = 0; j <= y; j++)
```

if [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). (*Note the `<=` part*).

to elaborate, for an array of dimension `p`, the valid indexes are `0` to `p-1`, inclusive.

You should change your loop conditions as `i < x` and `j < y` to stay withing the bounds. Accessing out of bound memory causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

- `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to conform to C standards for hosted environments.
- There is no need to make `grid` as VLA here. If the dimensions are already known, better approach is to use a compile-time constant (`#define`) to generate the array dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You're running past the *bounds* of the array. That's *undefined behaviour* in C, and is manifesting itself as a crash.

Change `i <= x` to `i < x` etc, or increase the grid size.